How do I switch to procedure view on Visual Studio Code?
My code has many functions. Is there a way to make it focus on only the function I am working on?
In the old days of Visual Basic Applications (VBA), there was a little icon to switch between
"Procedure view" and "Full module view"
In full module view, one sees the full module's code.
In Procedure view, the editor is limited to only the current function.


I think you can do this with a combination of the "Fold all except selected" and "unfold recursively" commands
